# Thread stopping in synchronized block

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem with a stopping thread which is in a synchronized block. I am using TCP socket. The problem is that I am waiting on a `DataInputStream` object and I want to create a new socket again but it doesn't allow me to do because of the synchronized block.

I have tried with `Thread.interrupted()`. I cannot avoid the synchronized block.  Is there any other way to do the same?

```
dis = new DataInputStream(ReadWriteData.kkSocket.getInputStream());
int i = -1;
String aval = ""; //new String();
char c = (char)dis.read();
```

It is getting blocked on `dis.read()`.

What I should do for escaping the `dis.read` when I want to create a new socket?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could always check if there is data available to read, by calling `dis.available()` to determine the number of bytes that can be read without blocking.

Using some additional logic could then allow for the creation of the new socket.

Answer (score 1):

You could close the stream and catch it that way, but that may not always be the best option.

Comment: I believe this is the recommended way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many streams you want to have you can do something like:

```
private static final int N_STREAMS = 3;
...
InputStream[] streams = new InputStream[N_STREAMS];
List<StringBuilder> outputBuilders = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
for (int i=0; i < N_STREAMS; i++) {
  // A StringBuilder for every stream
  outputBuilder.append(new StringBuilder());
  try {        
    streams[i] = new DataInputStream(ReadWriteData.kkSocket.getInputStream());
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // Propagate error or ignore?
  }
}

// Read data
for (int i=0; i < N_STREAMS; i++) {
  InputStream currentStream = streams[i];
  StringBuilder currentBuilder = outputBuilders.get(i);
  if (currentStream != null && currentStream.available() > 0) {
    try {
      currentBuilder.append(stream.read());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
  if (currentStream != null && currentStream??? == EOF) {
    // I don't know how to detect EOF on this stream...
    try {
      streams[i] = null; // Mark it as closed
      currentStream.close();
    } catch (...) {
      // Do something
    }
  }
}
// You know have a StringBuilder per socket; do with it what you want
```

As you might have noticed I don't know anything about Android. But this seems generic enough to fit your usage, or at least provide a hint.